# WindowBuilder issue

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, windowbuilder

I encountered a strange problem. I work with [Eclipse Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), I install all [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) insidious addiction, despite all that when I want to create a JFrame or something else I found just the palette!
[image]

Comment: Do you see Swing Designer. under which you will see JFrame

Comment: Well thanks, But i wanna get WindowBuilder work first ;)

Comment: it comes with the window builder itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With swing it is the new class wizard you need.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by new class wizazrd !

Comment: You appear to be using the new project wizard. Your should create a regular Java project, and then create a class using the WindowBuilder wizard.

Comment: There is not Two Wizards in Eclipse! it's the same one you can brought from different places.